# dotnet restore error on centos linux: access to path denied

Tags: linux, git, .net-core, centos7

I am running a TFS2017/VSTS build agent on a centos 7 server and during the build I am receiving the following error:

```
2017-05-23T02:35:57.4457330Z [command]/usr/local/bin/dotnet restore ./src/DocPropsService.sln
2017-05-23T02:35:59.8903860Z   Restoring packages for /myagent/_work/3/s/src/CommandService/DocProps.CommandService/DocProps.CommandService.csproj...
2017-05-23T02:36:09.8543710Z   Generating MSBuild file /myagent/_work/3/s/src/CommandService/DocProps.CommandService/obj/DocProps.CommandService.csproj.nuget.g.props.
2017-05-23T02:36:09.8786540Z /opt/dotnet/sdk/1.0.4/NuGet.targets(97,5): error : Access to the path '/myagent/_work/3/s/src/CommandService/DocProps.CommandService/obj/23507835-d558-4207-80a0-85b919019109.tmp' is denied. [/myagent/_work/3/s/src/DocPropsService.sln]
2017-05-23T02:36:09.8812240Z /opt/dotnet/sdk/1.0.4/NuGet.targets(97,5): error :   Permission denied [/myagent/_work/3/s/src/DocPropsService.sln]
```

The code is being checked out just fine by the build agent using git but the restore command is failing. The version of dotnet that I am using is 1.0.4.

I am not great with linux and not exactly sure where to start. Any kind of help would be very useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a last resort I manually removed all the data out of the source folder for the build and that work. I did have to use sudo do force this to delete but it seems to be working now. Not sure how it got into a state where I had to do this.